# Reload page re-send the data

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple code with `Flask`. I have a website with 4 buttons that when pressed send a POST to the `Flask` and returns the same page but with the button that tighten in another color. The states of each button are store in a bool array.
This is the `Flask` code:

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
states = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=bool)

@app.route('/control', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def control():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        val = int(request.form['change rele state'])
        states[val] = not states[val]

        return render_template('zapa.html', states=states)
    else:
        return render_template('zapa.html', states=states)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Control</h2>
  <p>Botones</p>

  <p>{{ states }}</p>

  <form action="/control" method="POST">
    {% for state in states %}
      {% if state == True %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="change rele state" value="{{ loop.index0 }}">Enchufe {{ loop.index }} Off</button>
      {% endif %}
      {% if state == False %}
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="change rele state" value="{{ loop.index0 }}">Enchufe {{ loop.index }} On</button>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that when pressing to reload the page, send as if pressed a button. Why? How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an incredibly deep understanding of flask, in fact none whatsoever, but to me it seems that you've made your server remember the state of this button you're talking about.

```
return render_template('zapa.html', states=states)
```

Rather than returning an altered **original** state, you're returning an altered version of the **previous** state on the POST with your 'change role state' request, and keeping the original value otherwise.

I think what you wanted to do (correct me if I'm wrong is the following)

```
@app.route('/control', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def control():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        val = int(request.form['change rele state'])
        current_states = states[:]
        current_states[val] = not current_states[val]
        return render_template('zapa.html', states=current_states)
    else:
        return render_template('zapa.html', states=states)
```

This creates a copy of the states, not altering it in global scope, so that next time control is invoked, the states list will be in its original state

This could be coded up more elegantly on my side, but I'm just trying to illustrate the issue.